# Wix installer Do I need to any Registry entries

Tags: xml, visual-studio, wix

Hi (Apologies for the question as a newbie),

I have a simple Question & Answer Application which is now finished and in order to deploy it I have chosen Wix Installer. Maybe a good learning curve but seems ok so far.

Installed will be a .exe, .xml and a number of .png & .rtf files in a typical directory structure. I think I am ok with writing the Wix Installer in XML and have detracted from using Heat to installer the couple hundred images as I don't mind keeping it all in the XML script. Heat will take time to learn and I am not sure I have that luxury.

Having read some of the tutorials and instructions I am unclear if I need any Registry entries in Windows ?? Can I do the entire install without Registry entries ?.

Kind Regards Kuldip (ps. I intend to have an Uninstall Option too!).

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your application or what you plan for the future with your installer. So you can perfectly go also without any registry keys if your application doesn't need any.
The uninstall-entry in the Add/Remove Programs (ARP) dialog will be created automatically by the Windows Installer. You can configure some of the values however, i.e. on how your application will appear there by setting the [ARP-properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368032(v=vs.85).aspx) accordingly. In Wix some of these can be configured using the attributes of the `Product`-element, like `Manufacturer`, `Name` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include adding anything to the registry in your installer if you don't find it necessary. However, you might find it useful for storing the location of your install.

For example: if you let users change the default install directory, when they come to upgrade it is likely that they will be prompted to upgrade to the default install directory again instead of their chosen install directory. Storing this value in the registry on install means you can then read it back on upgrades.